# xlwings does not write the data in an Excel file when trying to use VBA + Python

Tags: pandas, xlwings, yfinance, pandas.excelwriter

I have created this function in python:

---

def download_yahoo_data(arg1,arg2,arg3):

## This function downloads yahoo finance data given a start date and end date

## Inputs:

```
# arg1      ticker, from yahoo finance

# arg2      start date

# arg3      end date

import yfinance as yf

import os

import pandas as pd

df= yf.download(arg1,start=arg2,end=arg3,progress=False)

path = "C:\\Users\\Gregorio\\Desktop\\

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(path,arg1+".xlsx"),engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Data')

writer.save()

writer.close()
```

---

I calling this function from VBA using this VBA script:

Sub GetHistoricalData()

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

StartTime = Timer

arg1 = Sheets(1).[C4]                                   ' Yahoo finance ticker

arg2 = Application.Text(Sheets(1).[D4], "yyyy-mm-dd")   ' Start date

arg3 = Application.Text(Sheets(1).[E4], "yyyy-mm-dd")   ' End Date

RunPython ("import yahoo_downloader; yahoo_downloader.download_yahoo_data('" & arg1 & "','" & arg2 & "','" & arg3 & "')")

MinutesElapsed = Format((Timer - StartTime) / 86400, "hh:mm:ss")

MsgBox " This code ran sucessfully in " & MinutesElapsed & " minutes", vbInformation

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub

---

[When running my macro from VBA it looks like works properly, but when check the output file just contains the headers:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yayfy.jpg)

[however, in case I define the inputs in my IDE (Spyder) and run the program from spyder, it works properly:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Gyo.jpg)

---

def download_yahoo_data(arg1,arg2,arg3):

## This function downloads yahoo finance data given a start date and end date

## Inputs:

```
# arg1      ticker, from yahoo finance

# arg2      start date

# arg3      end date

import yfinance as yf

import os

import pandas as pd

df= yf.download(arg1,start=arg2,end=arg3,progress=False)

path = "C:\\Users\\Gregorio\\Desktop\\

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.join(path,arg1+".xlsx"),engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='Data')

writer.save()

writer.close()
```

arg1 = 'RR.L'

arg2 = "2018-07-21"

arg3 = "2022-07-21"

arg4 = download_yahoo_data(arg1,arg2,arg3)

---

I have done the same using Jupyter notebook and works properly.

Someone knows why reads properly the data from yahoo finance, but doesn't write it properly into the output file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, was not python o VBA script, was my excel that probably is too old, I have tried in other two different laptops with more recent excel versions and works pro